# Mean-Variance Criterion Derivation

Tags: taylor-expansion, finance, utility

Can you help me understand this derivation? This is finance related so $E[X]$ means the expected outcome (of a gamble) and $u(x)$ is the utility function.

> With any well-behaved utility function, when the range of possible
>   outcomes of a gamble is small relative to the risk tolerance of the
>   decision maker, the certainty equivalent of the gamble can be
>   approximated by making use of the local curvature of the utility
>   function.
>
> Consider a gamble $X$ with expected value $E[X]$ and variance $Var(X)$, and
>   a utility curve $u(x)$. From the first two terms of a Taylor series
>   expansion of $u(x)$ around the expected value $E[X]$ we obtain:
>
> $E[u(x)]=u(E[X])+1/2 u^{''}(E[X])Var(X)$ **i'm good here**
>
> We equate this expected utility to the utility of the certainty
>   equivalent $CE=E[X]+D$, where $D$ is a risk discount.
>
> Again, using a Taylor series expansion, $u(E[X]+D)$ can be approximated
>   by $u(E[X])+u''(E[X])D$. **how did we get to this approximation?**
>
> Hence the first order approximation for the risk discount is
>   $D = 1/2(u''/u') Var(X)$. **how did we get this result?**
>
> Therefore:
>
> $CE(X)=E[X]+1/2 (u''/u')Var(X)$ **how did we get to this conclusion?**
>
> The maximum EU (or maximum CE) principle reduces to a linear function
>   of mean and variance in which the relative weight given the variance
>   is half the local curvature of the utility function.

Thank you.

Comment: It's all Taylor series. Look at how to expand $f(x)$ and $f(x+h).$

Comment: I think the second approximation should have been
$u(E[X]+D) = u(E[X]) + u'(E[X]) D.$

Comment: I found a more intuitive derivation here: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/20628/utility-theory-certainty-equivalent-approximation-formula-derivation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the derivation here:
https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/20628/utility-theory-certainty-equivalent-approximation-formula-derivation

Here is a slightly modified version of that answer:

A second-order expansion near $ \bar{x}=E(x)$ gives:

$u(x)\approx u(\bar{x})+u'(\bar{x})(x-\bar{x})+1/2 u''(\bar{x})(x-\bar{x})^2$

Hence,

$E[u(x)]\approx u(\bar{x}) +\frac{1}{2} u''(\bar{x})Var(x)$

On the other hand, if we let c denote the certainty equivalent and assume it is close to $\bar{x}$, we can use the first-order expansion:

$u(c)\approx u(\bar{x})+u'(\bar{x})(c-\bar{x})$

We transform this equation to get:

$c=\bar{x}+\frac{u(c)-u(\bar{x})}{u'(\bar{x})}$

We can get the value of the numerator in the fraction part of the equation. We replace $E[u(x)]=u(c)$ in the previous formula to get:

$u(c)\approx u(\bar{x})+\frac{1}{2} u''(\bar{x}) Var(x)$

So that

$u(c)-u(\bar{x})\approx\frac{1}{2} u''(\bar{x}) Var(x)$

Therefore:

$c\approx\bar{x}+\frac{1}{2}(\frac{u''(\bar{x})}{u'(\bar{x})}) Var(x)$